# Apollo Client delays request

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a very weird issue with Apollo Client.

We are using apollo-client@1.9.3 with react (react-apollo@1.4.16).
In our project, we notice that apollo always wait for 1 to 2 seconds before sending the request.

Below is a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

This is how our client config looks like:

```
    const customNetworkInterface = {
    query: request =>
        fetch('/graphql', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default',

            headers: {
                Accept: '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                ...request,
                query: print(request.query),
            }),
        })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(({ data, errors }) => {
                if (errors) {
                    const userErrors = errors
                        .filter(({ code }) => +code >= 400 && +code <= 401)
                        .map(({ message }) => message)
                        .join('\n');
                    const serverErrors = errors
                        .filter(
                            ({ code }) => !code || (+code < 400 && +code > 401)
                        )
                        .map(({ message }) => message)
                        .join('\n');
                    if (serverErrors.length > 0) {
                        error(serverErrors);
                        if (isProduction) {
                            window.triggerAlert(
                                'danger',
                                'The server encountered an error. Our technical team has been notified.'
                            );
                        } else {
                            window.triggerAlert('danger', serverErrors);
                        }
                    } else if (userErrors.length > 0) {
                        window.triggerAlert('danger', userErrors);
                    }
                }

                return { data, errors };
            }),
};

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: '/graphql',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    },
});
networkInterface.useAfter([
    {
        applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
            response
                .clone()
                .json()
                .then(responseJson => {
                    if (responseJson.errors) {
                        error(
                            responseJson.errors
                                .map(({ message }) => message)
                                .join('\n')
                        );
                    }
                    next();
                });
        },
    },
]);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface: customNetworkInterface,
    queryDeduplication: true,
    addTypename: true,
});
```

Then the query code is with react-apollo:

```
graphql(RaceResultsQuery, {
    props: ({ ownProps, data }) => ({
        race_results: _.get(data, 'me.my_race_results', []),
    }),
}),
```

Comment: First things come to my mind are: a) that can be related to [query batching](https://blog.apollographql.com/query-batching-in-apollo-63acfd859862) b) [polling queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching). But you have to show the client creation / configuration and query code.

Comment: thanks for your tip. we are not using any batching or cache though. I have added our config code for the client.

Comment: Client creation / configuration seems to be default. What about client query code? How do you call that query on screenshot? Are you sure that it is delay of Apollo? May be better to log/trace first?

Comment: The client query code is pretty standard, we are using react-apollo. It is kind of hard to trace in this situation though. the console tells me the call is delayed happened at the graphql part.

Comment: May be `pollInterval` set somewhere? If it is set, it might delay first query for `pollInterval`. See: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching
Other wise, seems like application issue then...

Answer (score 0):

This would need a complete, minimal example to provide an answer for sure (delete as much of your code as possible with the issue still happening).

My guess would be that you have a parent component with a very expensive query and it only renders the component with the delayed query after the expensive query returned.

Answer (score 0):

This problems happens on my project too
There are 4 outgoing graphQL subscription requests in Chrome Network Tab
They have time gap exactly 1.2 secs